# Why is my hour parameter not working in node-cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, cron-task, node-cron

I am trying to run a cron job using node-cron every Monday at 8:30 so I use "30 8 * * Mon" which never runs (I also used "30 08 * * Mon" to be sure). After a bit of troubleshooting, I have seen that "30 * * * Mon" does work and runs on the 30th min of every hour. Can anyone help me figure this out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (*/30 08 * * Mon) and for any more queries visit  https://crontab.guru/#*/30_08_*_*_Mon

Comment: Great first answer! I recommend updating the answer to include the text from the link showing the verbal english break down for clarity. Also because sometimes links break.

Please add “At every 30th minute past hour 8 on Monday.” ;)